# Seeder class is suitable for this case?

Tags: laravel

I have a context where I have a CMS and a colors model and migration/table. But I want to have 10 colors loaded on the CMS by default. The users can add more, delete, edit each color but at first there should be there 10 colors by default.

My doubt is how to properly achieve this, I was reading the documentation and it seems that seeder classes are for testing purposes, but in this case it was not for a test, it was really to populate the colors table with 10 initial default colors. Do you know how to properly achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can use seeder in this case as you want some per-defiend data. You can read this as well . https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding

Comment: Thanks, but so in this case I need to enter 10 different inserts like this "DB::table('colors')->insert([
            'hexcode' => "#ebebeb",
            'name' => "gray"        ]);" and repeat this code 10 different times for the 10 different initial colors? Thanks!

Comment: yes you can add multiple inserts as well as can run an sql dump file as well.